# Is it possible to connect a google colab notebook to google cloud so I can get more RAM?

Tags: python, cloud, google-colaboratory

Or alternatively, is it possible to use google colab with amazon ec2? I need more RAM and am willing to pay for it but I like the colab environment because its so easy.

I know this question was answered a few times over the years, but perhaps things have changed since.

Comment: [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) doubles the amount of RAM available in the free version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read how to do it here.

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

There are other articles that explain in more details, just google "Colab GCP".